# write a very simple cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Wonder if anyone can point me to or give an example of a cookie which does the following;

1) On loading a members page it serves the cookie 
2) on visiting a non members page it checks for the cookie.

e.g. 
if member display 'X' else display 'log in'

Comment: Have you tried to do it? If so can you post your attempt. Its kind of hard to see where you may be going wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: so you want to write in a cookie, then read this cookie. Quite the normal usage for cookies. Then the  "someone" you're looking for is probably Google.

Comment: Hi, I can't post a code as I cant find any examples of what I require. Basically I need to pass from a rhtml to a php page. In short I need a separate cookie writing in the members page so when a member loads a normal page I can use the if statement to decide which details to show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the cookie(s) using php's [setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) method

```
setcookie("isLoggedIn", $value, time() + 3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("otherData", $data, time() + 3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

Then on page load, you check the value, if it's set then set the display text.

```
var loggedIn = getCookie("isLoggedIn);
if(loggedIn == true) 
{
    // Get other data and display it
    var otherData = getCookie("otherData");
}  
else print "log in" // Of course set the link text here instead of print
```

Here's a function to getCookies:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help with this. Main problem is I can't use a hidden div as the content needs to be completely hidden from the user unless they are logged in as it will contain a discount code (for members only)

Comment: ohh I see. Well to set the cookie using javascript, the content will need to be available on the user side. You need to set the cookie using server side code. Which language are us using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The members area is rhtml and the rest of the site is php

Comment: Hi, thanks but is it possible to set the cookie without php? I cant get php running in the members area sadly e.g. javascript?
Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Javascript is client side, if you set the cookies using javascript then the end user will get access to all data whether they're logged in or not. But yes, it is possible to set it using only javascript.